# Selenium - how to dismiss proxy login popup

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using free proxies with Selenium, and everything works fine, except for the case when the proxy requires authentication. In this case, the browser displays the login popup, but since it's the proxy server which requires authentication, the standard way of handling alerts doesn't seem to work.
Currently my code looks like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)

try:
    driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
    raise ProxyFailed
except NoAlertPresentException:
    pass

driver.get(url)

try:
    driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
    raise ProxyFailed
except NoAlertPresentException:
    pass
```

When the proxy server requires authentication I want only to dismiss the dialog box, since I don't have any credentials.
The problem is, the dialog seems to block the `driver.get` call and waits for user input (the first `try` block executes, but the program never reaches the second one).
I can't just remove these problematic proxies from the list, because proxy gathering is also automated and happens every time the program starts.
Searching through the internet, I only found this `switch_to.alert` method for handling login popups.

Alternatively, is there a way to disable the popup in Chrome, so it just displays a `401` error page and doesn't wait for user input?

I'm using Python 2.7 on Linux, but the software should also run on Windows.

---

EDIT: This is the dialog I'm talking about:
[dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbSvN.png)
The text translates to:

> Log in
>   Proxy server [server address] requires the user name and password.
>   Your connection to this site is not private.
>   User name [input]
>   Password [input]
>   [Log in] [Cancel]

What I need is to click the cancel button with Selenium.

Comment: Do you get any exception? If yes, what kind?

Comment: No, I did not get any exceptions, just the driver.get seems to be blocked. Of course, I'm getting NoAlertPresentException in first try block, and then the same in the second one when I close the login popup manually.

Comment: Isn't the proxy dialog a operationg-system dialog? OS dialogs are by its nature unreachable for any script. Maybe better to inspect, why is the dialog even apearing.

Comment: It looks like Chrome dialog, it's not styled as other OS elements, and is attached to the Chrome window, but maybe Chrome has an ability to display OS dialogs as its own, I don't really know. When I encounter this again, I'll post a screenshot.